# Excel hyper link function doesn't get converted to PDF

Tags: excel, pdf

I am developing a small excel plugin. As part of it I need to convert my excel document to PDF format. How can I do that? All the plugins and printers that I've found do not convert links created by the hyperlink function.

I know this is not programmatically related per say, but I am developing this software, and vba is quite a reasonable solution.

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure any solution will work using the hyperlink function. The reason is typically the convert to PDF functions like a printer driver and the 'printer' only gets the helper text information not the underlying URL. But, using [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/index.aspx), any text formatted like a URL "http://www.stackoverflow.com" for example, will get converted to a clickable URL (in the modern readers).